# Format Date Time generating errors in log

Tags: java, oracle11g, pega

I am using the following function for formatting DateTime

```
FormatDateTime(UniversalIndexingPage.DateOfDocument, "DD-MON-YY", "", "")
```

However i am getting the following error in the log

```
|10.67.60.74 - Cannot create format "DD-MON-YY"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'O'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:575)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:500)
at com.pega.ibm.icu.impl.pega.LocaleElements.getSimpleDateFormat(LocaleElements.java:975)
at com.pega.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:93)
at com.pega.pegarules.pub.util.PRDateFormat.createRealFormat(PRDateFormat.java:1544)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Please help!

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? I don't think it could be any clearer.

Comment: Why does it say illegal pattern Character 'O'

Comment: Because `O` is an illegal character in your format.

Comment: You want dd-MM-yyyy I suspect... or dd-MM-yy if you *really* want 2-digit years.

Comment: But there is no compilation error , nor is there any error on the UI, however there is error generated in the Log

Comment: Jon, i want 2 digits year

Comment: Why would there be a compilation error? You pass it a String that needs to be parsed and used to generate the pattern. That can only be caught at run time.

Comment: So any help on how i fix this because as far as i know this should be a valid character

Comment: With all the open source loggers out there, why would you try to roll your own?

Comment: Because this a PEGA PRPC issue and not exactly java, however since PEGA PRPC is built on java, i was hoping the java community could help shed some light on the issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 3-character months, try the pattern "dd-MMM-yy" instead of "DD-MON-yy".

See This doc for the patterns: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Capital 'D' is for day in the year (1-365), which I don't believe is what you want.